# Downloading a document from a WCF Service to a web page

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, html, datajs

I am new to web development and I am looking for some advice on the best solution for this scenario.

I have a WCF service, and a page written using HTML5, javascript (knockout j's and dataJs)

I access my WCF service using DataJS. This works perfectly for receiving and sending data to a from  my web page.

But now I have to be able to upload and download files to and from the server.

I have seen people recommend streaming to and from the WCF service, but I am not sure how I would handle this stream on the client side (javascript/datajs), or if it is the best solution?

I have also come across XMLHttpRequest, but again I am not sure if this would be the best route to follow.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WCF, but commonly use PHP for this task. This seems like a great tutorial on it: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php